# Localhost via WAMP doesn't connect

Tags: localhost, hosts, wamp

I needed to change the default port wamp was listening to, so now I need to use another one, let's say 81. So now instead of going to `http://localhost` now I need to go to `http://localhost:81`. No problem with that, but if I try to start it directly with WAMP, it attempts connecting `http://localhost` and of course, nothing happens.

How can I configure WAMP to go directly to `http://localhost:81`?